# Get HTTP Request Body from basicHttpBinding of WCF proxy

Tags: c#, wcf, basichttpbinding

I am calling a WCF service hosted in IIS over HTTP, using `basicHttpBinding`. In order to pass validation on the server, a custom header value must be passed, computed from the HTTP request itself (headers and body if present).

I can get most of the information from the call using a client message inspector (`System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IClientMessageInspector`) custom endpoint behavior on the proxy (`System.ServiceModel.Description.IEndpointBehavior`), and then accessing the `httpRequest` header of the message object.

However, getting the message contents that are serialized to send across the wire don't appear to be immediately or obviously available. I can get the message itself, however, that's stored in an XmlSerializer, which doesn't make it available in the same format as how it will be sent over the wire.

Is there a way to access this value? Perhaps another inspector or behavior that can be injected, so that it is invoked at the time the channel binding is opened or accessed?

Comment: It seems that going via the endpoint or behaviors route is unlikely to be possible. Is it possible (within reason) to have a derived basicHttpBinding class where the HTTP communications can be manipulated in some fashion?

Answer (score 3):

You have to implement a custom `IDispatchMessageInspector`, and inject it in an `IOperationBehavior` or `IEndpointBehavior` attribute. (in the `ApplyDispatchBehavior()` method)

In the `AfterReceiveRequest()` method of an `IDispatchMessageInspector`, you can get the message body only by copying it (it's invalid once accessed) :

```
private String GetRequestBody(ref Message message)
{
    MessageBuffer buffer = message.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
    message = buffer.CreateMessage();
    String xml = null;
    try
    { 
        var copy = buffer.CreateMessage();
        var dicReader = copy.GetReaderAtBodyContents();
        xml = dicReader.ReadOuterXml();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
    return xml;
}
```

But if you just want to find a header value, you can simply get it with :

```
private String TryGetHeader(Message request, String headerName)
{
    if (request.Headers.FindHeader(headerName, "HeaderMessageNamespace") != -1)
        return request.Headers.GetHeader<String>(headerName, "HeaderMessageNamespace");
    return null;
}
```

Create an attribute like this one, and put it on the method you want to track in your WCF service :

```
    public class MyOperationBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IOperationBehavior
    {
        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
        {
            if (dispatchOperation.Parent.MessageInspectors.OfType<MyMessageInspector>().Any() == false)
                dispatchOperation.Parent.MessageInspectors.Add(new MyMessageInspector());
        }
        [...]
    }
```

and implements the inspector like this :

```
    public class MyMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            var result = TryGetHeader(request, "name");
            return null;
        }
        [...]
    }
```

AND for the client side :

You have to inject the behavior just after the service instantiation. With a MyServiceClient of type ClientBase, and a IEndpointBehavior myBehavior :

```
((ClientBase<ISomething>)service).Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(myBehavior);
```

with

```
public class MyBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new MyMessageInspector());
    }
    [...]
}
```

Comment: I've created an `IDispatchMessageInspector` and have tried to inject it in the `IEndpointBehavior`, within the `ApplyDispatchBehavior()` method, but it doesn't appear that the method gets called. Perhaps it needs to be in an `IOperationBehavior`, however, I can't seem to locate where I would attach the custom Operation Behavior.

Comment: Is this on the server? I'm trying to do this on the client side via a proxy class (generated by Visual Studio/svcutil), for every operation. This seems to be for the server side, or did I miss something?

Comment: This is for server side yes.. I add you a sample for client side

Comment: Ok, but that's what I already have, which gives me access to the HTTP headers, and the WCF (Soap) message body, but not the HTTP request contents. Unless I am missing where I can add an `IDispatchMessageInspector` to the `ClientMessageInspectors`, since there is no `MessageInspectors` property on the `ClientRuntime` class

Comment: In WCF you are at the application layer level (OSI 7). If you want to intercept the session header or the TCP/IP header, it's impossible. If you want to read / write custom header values in your message, that's where you should work.

Comment: From what I read on msdn, IDispatchMessageInspector are for service side operation. Not client side : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx